# Finding the peak of this unimodal sequence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, binomial-distribution, order-statistics, beta-function

Consider the function:

$h\left(m,n,p\right):=\frac{n-1}{m}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-2\\
n-m-1
\end{array}\right)\cdot\int_{0}^{p}x^{n-m-1}\left(1-x\right)^{m-1}dx$

for $m=1,\ldots,n$, $n\geq2$ and $p\in\left(0,1\right)$. Show that
it is unimodal wrt $m$ and determine the term $m^{*}$ that corresponds
to the peak of $h\left(\cdot,n,p\right)$.

Here are my steps so far. I consider the difference:
\begin{aligned}h\left(m,n,p\right)-h\left(m-1,n,p\right)= & \frac{n-1}{m}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-2\\
n-m-1
\end{array}\right)\cdot\int_{0}^{p}x^{n-m-1}\left(1-x\right)^{m-1}dx\\
 & -\frac{n-1}{m-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-2\\
n-m
\end{array}\right)\cdot\int_{0}^{p}x^{n-m}\left(1-x\right)^{m-2}dx\\
= & \frac{n-1}{m\left(m-1\right)}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-2\\
n-m
\end{array}\right)\cdot\int_{0}^{p}x^{n-m-1}\left(1-x\right)^{m-2}\cdot\left\{ n\cdot\left(1-x\right)-m\right\} dx
\end{aligned}

The sign of the difference is determined by the term in brackets which
is strictly decreasing in $x$ and it is first positive and then negative
as $x$ goes from $0$ to $p$. Hence, $h\left(\cdot,n,p\right)$
must have a unique peak at $m^{*}$. But can we specify $m^{*}$ in
closed form? It seems that $m^{*}$ is close to and greater than $n\cdot\left(1-p\right)$...
How to formally show that?

Comment: Note the connection to
the order statistics distribution of $F$: $h\left(m,n,p\right)=\frac{1}{m}\cdot F_{n-m:n-1}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{m}\cdot\sum_{k=n-m}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1\\
k
\end{array}\right)F\left(x\right)^{k}\left(1-F\left(x\right)\right)^{n-k-1}, p=F\left(x\right)$.

Comment: Note also that $\frac{n-1}m\binom{n-2}{n-m-1}$ simplifies to $\binom{n-1}m$. What's the source of this problem?

Comment: You are right @joriki, thank you. I am doing research in economics and my work is related to order statistics. Btw due to the connection with the Binomial distribution, it seems that it may have one or two peaks, depending on $n$ and $p$. I am interested in characterizing these peaks in closed-form.

Comment: Thank you @metamorphy, this is correct. If it helps, we also have
the following representation:

\begin{aligned}h\left(m,n+1,p\right)= & \frac{1}{m}\cdot F_{n+1-m:n}\left(x\right)\\
= & \frac{1}{m}\cdot\int_{0}^{p}f_{n+1-m:n}\left(x\right)dx\\
= & \frac{n}{m}\cdot\int_{0}^{p}\left(F_{n-m:n-1}\left(x\right)-F_{n+1-m:n-1}\left(x\right)\right)f\left(x\right)dx
\end{aligned}

Comment: If you find parameters that lead to more than one peak, let me know, I'd be interested. It seemed quite intuitive that there should be only one.

Comment: @joriki: Take n = 10 and p = 0.530981. Then, plotting $h\left(m,n,p\right)$ gives two equal consecutive peaks at m1= 6 and m2 = 7. I noticed this after posting the question but I am not surprised due to the connection to the Binomial PDF. Any suggestions of finding those maxima?

Comment: Ah, I see, I wouldn't call that two peaks :-) Of course, since you can vary $p$ continuously, you can make two of the values near the maximum equal. But it's still unimodal, there are not two separate peaks with lower values in between. That would have surprised me somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof for my claim. The coefficients $d_{k}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1\\
k-1
\end{array}\right)\,p^{k}\,\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}$ correspond to the density of the Binomial distribution with parameters
$n-1$ and $p$ with a unique mode at $\left\lfloor n\cdot p\right\rfloor $.
Then, $h\left(m,n,p\right)$ corresponds to the running average $\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m}d_{k}$.
Let $m^{*}$ be the (unique) maximizer of $h\left(\cdot,n,p\right)$.
It is well known that the running average of a monotone sequence follows
the same monotonicity. Thus, if  $d_{1}>d_{k}$ for $2\leq k\leq n-1$,
then $m^{*}=1$. Similarly, if $d_{k}<d_{n-1}$ for $1\leq k\leq n-2$,
then $m^{*}=n-1$. However, if $d_{k}$ is interior unimodal, $m^{*}$
is greater or equal to the maximizer of $d_{k}$. Overall, $m^{*}\geq\left\lfloor n\cdot p\right\rfloor $.